# Replacement for Apache Xalan TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: java, xalan

I found the following code in an old Java project. I would like to remove `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`, because Apache Xalan has a [security issue](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-XALAN-2953385) and it seems to be retired.

```java
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;


TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", SomeSVGDocument.class.getClassLoader());
```

Now I wonder if can switch to the following code:

```java
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

Can I do that or do I need to search for a replacement for `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and should, for more info check this [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) page. Most Java distributions like the [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-glance.html) and [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/) now incorporates Xalan internally. So now there is no need for an external dependency to Apache Xalan. The version that most JDKs incorporate still implement XSLT version 1.0. The XSLT version 1.0 is not bad, but if you need additional XSLT processing functionality then you can consider something like [SaxonJ](https://www.saxonica.com/download/java.xml) which implements XSLT version 3.0.